# Why do we use simple tense to say a story in the past?

Tags: tense, past-simple, present-simple

I have just watched "**Kevin Hart: What Now?**".

Kevin is standing on the stage & he is talking a story about himself. He said:

"**One day, I go to a store....**", he used a lot of simple present tenses while he was talking about his story. But sometimes he used simple past too. EX:

"**And I came back....**"

My question is:

**Why do we use simple tense to say a story in the past?**

Comment: You probably mean why do we use simple present, not "simple tense." Meanwhile, it's used as a storytelling technique to make you feel immersed in the story. See [here](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic45770.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damon_Runyon).

Comment: Comedy is sort of a special case.  The objective isn't to comply with English rules.  Rules are purposely broken to achieve an objective.  And it may sound like simple, off-the-cuff conversation, but it is extensively rehearsed and polished to sound that way.  Each word and pause is there for a reason.  The bottom line is that it's counter-productive to try to analyze what comedians say as if it's normal English.

Comment: The present, simple or continuous, is one of the options a storyteller has when narrating a tale.  One could say that the present adds a kind of immediacy to the story, rather like the verbal analog of raw unedited video footage. The action is presented as something that is unfolding.